# set up pipenv with supervisor

Tags: python, gunicorn, supervisord, pipenv

I want to deploy dev server but I have a problem with starting celery and gunicorn. I'm using scripts for my purposes

celery.sh

```
#!/bin/bash 
cd /home/dev/app
pipenv run celery -A config worker -B -l info
```

and start.sh for gunicorn

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/dev/app
pipenv run gunicorn config.wsgi:application -b 127.0.0.1:8005 -w 2 -t 60 \

    --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE \

    --env DSN=$SENTRY_DSN \

    --env DATABASE_URL=$DATABASE_URL \

    --log-file - \

    --error-logfile /home/dev/app/errors.log
```

Also here is my config for supervisor

```
[program:back]
directory=/home/dev/app/
command=/home/dev/bin/start
user=dev
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stopsignal=QUIT
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true


[program:celery]
directory=/home/dev/app/
command=/home/dev/bin/celery
user=dev
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stopsignal=QUIT
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

When I'm running `sudo supervisorctl start celery` I'm getting the following error:
`/home/dev/bin/celery: line 3: pipenv: command not found`

Also I added the following lines as pipenv documentation says (https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/diagnose/)

```
[supervisord]
environment=LC_ALL='en_US.UTF-8',LANG='en_US.UTF-8'
```

### UPDATE

Changed my supervisor config:

```
[program:back]
directory=/home/dev/app/
command=pipenv run gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8005
user=dev
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stopsignal=QUIT
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true


[program:celery]
directory=/home/dev/app/
command=pipenv run celery -A config:celery_app worker -B -l info
user=dev
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stopsignal=QUIT
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

And now I'm getting an error:

```
back: ERROR (no such file)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give explicit path of gunicorn. Though I'm not sure about pipenv, but the error you are getting is because supervisor tries to find gunicorn in the directory. You should change your config file into something like this:

```
[program:back]
directory=/home/dev/app/
command=/path/to/pipenv run /path/to/gunicorn config.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8005
```

Then you must restart your supervisord in order to load the settings.

> sudo service supervisord reload

Comment: How can I find the path of the **gunicorn** when installed in virtual environment?

Comment: @AnujTBE it is generally `/path-to-env/bin/gunicorn` else you can do a grep on the folder

Answer (score -1):

> in your config file. change `command=` to `bash -c` followed by the full path and file to execute
>   this should do the trick