# Run pipenv from supervisor

Tags: supervisord, pipenv

On my Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, I have installed `pipenv` using `pip3`. I also installed `supervisor`.

**My goal:**

I want supervisor to run my `test.sh` script containing `pipenv run` command.

**My `test.sh` script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

/root/local/bin/pipenv run echo "2222222"
```

**My supervisor config in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/mysite.conf`:**

```
[program:mysite]

command = /var/www/mysite/test.sh
user = root
stdout_logfile = /var/www/mysite/.gunicorn/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log
redirect_stderr = true                                                     
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

**My Problem:**

When  I run `/var/www/mysite/test.sh` directly from console, everything works as expected. However If supervisor runs my bash script using config above, following clueless trace is thrown.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 396, in run
    command=command, args=args, three=state.three, python=state.python, pypi_mirror=state.pypi_mirror
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 2217, in do_run
    ensure_project(three=three, python=python, validate=False, pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 601, in ensure_project
    validate=validate, skip_requirements=skip_requirements, system=system
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 324, in ensure_pipfile
    project.create_pipfile(python=python)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 644, in create_pipfile
    config_parser = ConfigOptionParser(name=self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/baseparser.py", line 141, in __init__
    assert self.name
AssertionError
```

Any ideas why supervisor cannot launch my bash script properly? I suspect it is because pipenv when launched by supervisor is missing certain environment variables.

Please notice all my paths are absolute, as suggested here: [set up pipenv with supervisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948425/set-up-pipenv-with-supervisor)

Comment: I have the exact same error messages but with just running `pipenv install` normaly. Any solutions fpr that?